# ExeConfigurationFileMap not finding section in file but ConfigurationFileMap is

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

Finding a custom section in a config file works when I use a path to a file, but when I pass in an exe config file map of the same thing it fails. Why?

```
string file = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(PhotoComparison)).Location + ".config";

var efm = new ExeConfigurationFileMap() { ExeConfigFilename = file };
var cfm new ConfigurationFileMap(file)

//returns entry
var o2 = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration(cfm).GetSection("presetFilters");

//returns null
var o3 = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration(efm).GetSection("presetFilters");
```

Answer (score 0):

.NET applications use a hierarchy of config files. I find [this diagram](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19675/Cracking-the-Mysteries-of-NET-Configuration#t1_1) describes well the situation.

The way you are using `ExeConfigurationFileMap`, you are setting the **executable configuration file**. However you are calling the method `OpenMappedMachineConfiguration` which should only load the **machine configuration file**.

I think you are not actually loading the file you want. Maybe this would work for you :

```
string file = "some config ...";    
// ExeConfigFilename => MachineConfigFilename
var efm = new ExeConfigurationFileMap() { MachineConfigFilename = file };  
var o3 = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration(efm).GetSection("presetFilters");
```